# Disable Throttling on a single list

Tags: list-view-threshold, resource-throttling

I want to disable list throttling on a particular list using PowerShell, will this cause any performance issues when the list contains more than 20000 items?

Answer (score 2):

Well you may find similar code for disabling throttling of a SharePoint list but one thing I don’t like is specifying SharePoint objects without taking care of case sensitivity, as Powershell will not recognize objects.

```
$WebURL = "http://local/Sites/Solutions"    
$ListName = "YouDesiredList"    
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL    
$List = $Web.Lists[$ListName]    
$list.EnableThrottling = $false    
$List.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended scenario. Microsoft is saying that it might cause performance problems. In my experience it depends on hardware resources, number of concurrent users accessing the list. I would really suggest, if possible, to test it first. 20000 is quite a lot (when you consider 5000 throttling default limit).

It is recommended to either split items into folders (in the same list) or create views filtered by indexed column. Usually there is not many scenarios where users need to be returned more than 5000 items, but I understand that there might be such requirement.

Comment: There is a very nic article, describing why it causes performance degradation:
http://www.future-processing.pl/blog/sharepoint/

Comment: Throttling is enabled for a good reason.  Disabling throttling can cause performance problems.  If you need to disable throttling for a specific list, I recommend moving the site collection containing the list to a dedicated content database.  This way if SQL table locking performance issues would be contained to the sites in that content database [reference]<http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mimorr/archive/2012/08/28/disable-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling-at-the-list-level.aspx>

Answer (score 1):

Use this to disable throttling for a single list:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://url/sites/web
$list = $web.Lists["List Name"]
$list.EnableThrottling = $false
$list.Update()
```