# How to raise throttle limit or remove throttle limit with sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, resource-throttling

I have done lots of research trying to answer this question but nothing seems to work correctly. I have a list that stores tons of values and when interacting with it there is always a throttle limit reached message.

I have tried solutions such as the ones in [Disable Throttling on a single list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98576/disable-throttling-on-a-single-list)

and

```
Below steps will help to change list view threshold view at the web application level.
```

• Login to Central Admin.

• Go to Application Management -> Manage Web Applications.

• Pick the Web application for which you want to change the threshold value.

• In the ribbon above, click General Settings. That will bring down a menu, from which you should pick Resource Throttling.

• Change the List View Threshold value.

Nothing seems to work unfortunately so any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific in terms of what you're seeing. The PowerShell link the linked thread is the correct way to disable throttling and does function.

Comment: I always get an error saying that Get-SPWeb is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, etc. Once I got this error I went on to find more solutions    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122585/powershell-error-the-term-get-spweb-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet does not seem to work.  Should I be using Sharepoint Online management tool or just a normal powershell? Or is it something else

Comment: OK, you're running the SharePoint Management Shell on the SharePoint server 'as administrator', correct?

Comment: I am running it as admin

Comment: My site is hosted on the cloud if that matters at all

Comment: SharePoint Online? If that's the case, you cannot adjust throttling. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-B8588DAE-9387-48C2-9248-C24122F07C59#ID0EAABAAA=Online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trevor has the correct answer that throttling cannot be modified for SharePoint Online. But to add a bit, while it's possible to do so on-prem, it's not recommended. If you're getting this error, the correct approach is to configure indexed fields and/or adjust your queries, rather than try to get around the features that were added to maintain performance.